# Combining non-adjacent partitions

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, grub, gparted

I mainly use Linux Mint, but have a dual-boot setup with Windows 10. I choose which OS to boot in Grub on boot up.

My partitions look like this from Windows:

[image: Disc layout]

I want to add the space from the (empty) Recovery D: partition to the Windows C: partition, but my important Linux partition is between them.

How can I do this safely? I assume Gparted, but unsure of the steps to take. It seems there is no way to do this without moving the start of my Linux partitions, which seems unsafe?

(The reason I want to do this is in order to have enough space for extra 7GB Windows reserves for updates from 1903. If someone knows a way to force Windows to use a certain partition for this, it would be even better and I wouldn't need to do this partitioning.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used `gparted` quite a lot for this sort of thing and never had a problem, but you can't assume that you won't (including a power failure), so the first thing you **must** do is make a full disc back-up, and a Linux partition back-up as well, if you want to be really safe.

Then in `gparted` delete the recovery partition, if you are absolutely sure it's empty.

Now move partition 5 to the end of the disc and then partition 4 adjacent to it.

Finally the windows partition can now be extended to use all the space below the Linux partition.

Note that `gparted` makes no changes until you press the `Apply` button, so you can abort and restart at any point until you do this, so make this the very last thing you do after you have set up the partition layout you want.

You are wise to be cautious, but provided you have adequate back-up you can proceed with confidence: `gparted` does quite a lot to protect you from making an unusable layout, and scans all disc areas before making modifications, which makes the process quite slow, but at least it's safe.

Comment: I've just noticed that I have crossed with gronostaj's answer, but I'll let mine stand, as I have included more of the details of the process.

Comment: Thanks! This did the job. Had some small problem booting into Windows afterwards, but running Boot Repair from a Ubuntu live USB fixed it.

Comment: Glad it's solved. I've used `boot-repair` a few times and it has always worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The most important part: **make full disk backups**. I'd use Clonezilla.

Moving Linux partitions is usually safe. Just avoid using built-in Windows tools (Disk Management, diskpart), as they do weird and unsafe stuff such as sorting GPT partitions. Gparted shouldn't do anything stupid.

Please note that moving partition's start (ie. shrinking/extending left or moving entire partition) requires rewriting entire partition contents. This will take some time and put some strain on SSDs. It's not a big deal if you do that every now and then, but try to avoid it where possible.

In case it's not obvious: you can't modify a partition you're booting from, so you'll want to boot Linux from USB to do this. I like to use [GRML](https://grml.org/). It includes Clonezilla too.